# Unable to access PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file in which I store user information. The filename is **johndoe** (with no extension):

**johndoe**

```
John,Doe,JohnDoe,johndoe@gmail.com,abcd1234
```

I am trying to get `John`, `Doe` and `JohnDoe` from the file in this way:

**index.php**

```
$filename = explode("/", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[2];
$userpath = "http://192.168.0.1/member/" . $filename;
$userfile = fopen($userpath,"r");
$username = explode(",",fgets($userfile))[2];
$firstname = explode(",",fgets($userfile))[0];
$lastname = explode(",",fgets($userfile))[1];
```

where `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` currently returns `/member/johndoe/index.php`.

When I print the array `explode(",",fgets($userfile))` using `print_r()`, I get:

```
Array ( [0] => John [1] => Doe [2] => JohnDoe [3] => johndoe@gmail.com [4] => abcd1234 )
```

However, I can't access any of the array elements. For example, echoing `explode(",",fgets($userfile))[2]` throws an error:

> **Notice:** Undefined offset: 2 in 192.168.0.1/member/johndoe/index.php on line 8

Comment: Why do you read the file multiple times? Read once, store the array resulted by the split in a variable and use it multiple times. `fgets` will _not_ reset the file, it will try to read the next string. Which will be empty on the second read.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it will read the next line on calling `fgets()` multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), the file pointer will move to the byte right next to the last one it just read.

You don't need to call it every time:

```
$filename = explode("/", $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])[2];
$userpath = "http://192.168.0.1/member/" . $filename;
$userfile = fopen($userpath,"r");

// Split into parts and assign values to corresponding variables
list($firstname, $lastname, $username) = explode(',', fgets($userfile));

// Alternative syntax (PHP 7.1+)
// [$firstname, $lastname, $username] = explode(',', fgets($userfile));
```